# Sending SSH shell commands with Apache SSHD

Tags: java, apache, ssh, sshd

I am trying to send commands to an SSH shell using the [Apache SSHD library](http://mina.apache.org/sshd-project/index.html). I have read the JavaDoc; but it is so sparse that I am having trouble understanding how to use the library.

I'm sorry I can't link to JavaDoc, but it doesn't seem to be available on the web. I am able to set up a test that sends commands and reads results using the System.in, System.out, and System.err streams. The end goal of the project though is to send a String to the shell, process the results, send another string, process the results, etc while staying in the same shell. I know I can open up multiple ChannelExecs; but that creates multiple channels.

Essentially, I want to my program to interact with the shell.

Answer (score 0):

https://mina.apache.org/sshd-project/tips.html

I had to modify their snippet a bit, here's what worked for me:

```
sshd.setCommandFactory(new CommandFactory() {
            public Command createCommand(String command) {
                return new ProcessShellFactory(" ")).create();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Answer (score -1):

If you want a fully customized and controlled shell, then you can write your own implementation for org.apache.sshd.server.Command class and inside run() method, call the java.lang.Process to execute your own shell/DOS scripts and return results to the calling program via input and output streams of Command class.

If the calling programs can execute normal shell commands like dir / mkdir / touch etc, then you can use org.apache.sshd.server.shell.InvertedShell class.
There is a test class InvertedShellWrapperTest.java in the Apache SSHD package to give you a head start.